# Google Maps instant zoom-out on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map with multiple pins representing store locations. I zoom in until I see fewer locations and when I click on one of the red pins I get an instant zoom-out. No errors are popping up in the browser's console (Chrome and Firefox - latest versions).

Have a quick look at the screecast below:
https://monosnap.com/file/FEIB5YdvbSaQd5iiFZ363bfCXJryOt

Has anybody encountered this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: added demonstration screencast

Comment: I can't debug a screencast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I haven't encountered this because whenever I use google maps markers, I add an eventListener to them that controls the zoom. For instance:

```
marker.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //zooms in on the location you clicked
  map.setZoom(18);
  map.setCenter(data.location);
});
```

I'm not positive but google maps api probably as a default value set whenever you click on a marker. If you edit your question with your code I might be able to answer a bit better.